# GVariant , decompile or not

Tags: c, glib, conceptual

I have a `GVariant file`, But i don't any information about `GVarinat` and the given file.I have been started to reading `devhelp`, (GVariant section)

My information of file are:

```
mohsen@debian:~$file gschemas.compiled
gschemas.compiled: GVariant Database file, version 0
mohsen@debian:~$file -ib gschemas.compiled
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

**Questions is:** Does `GVariant` format need to compile? Do i need to decompile it?  If true, How can i decompile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GVariant Database is the binary format used by [gvdb](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gvdb).  That file is compiled from XML files using [glib-compile-schemas](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/glib-compile-schemas.html).

I'm having trouble thinking of a situation where decompiling would be useful, which explains why I don't think anyone has written a tool to do it (if that is possible).  Without knowing what you're trying to do it's hard to know if you need to decompile it, but my guess is that you don't since you should already have the XML files, and GSettings uses the binary format.

Comment: `gvdb` doesn't main function, maybe it's librarary source.

Comment: Yes, it's a library.  The code for glib-compile-schemas is at https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/glib-compile-schemas.c